# Why is my autocomplete function not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I've got a jQuery autocomplete function that is working perfectly fine untill I rewrite the source with a function.

The odd part is that both functions are returning the exact same data, however, when I add an ajax function to the source, the autocomplete function no longer works.

**Working code:**

```
    $('#q').autocomplete({
    source:'getklanten.php'

    }).data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li>" )
        .append( "<a>" + item.naam + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
   };
```

This code returns in console

```
GET http://myURL/getklanten.php?term=comp
[{"naam":"Company name","id":12345}]
```

And the autocomplete function works as intended and returns the result.

**Not working code with variable function:**

```
var dynamicVar = $('#zxc').prop('checked');

$('#zxc').change(function(){
    dynamicVar = $('#zxc').prop('checked');
    dynamicVar = $('#zxc').is(':checked');
    console.log(dynamicVar);
});

$('#q').autocomplete({
    //source:'getklanten.php'
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "getklanten.php",
          data: {
            term : request.term,
            supplier : $('#zxc').is(':checked')
          }
        });
    }
}).data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li>" )
    .append( "<a>" + item.naam + "</a>" )
    .appendTo( ul );
};
```

This code returns in console:

```
GET http://myURL/getklanten.php?term=comp&supplier=false
[{"naam":"Company name","id":12345}]
```

However, this breaks the autocomplete function. Without any errors. Even though both functions return the exact same data..
Could someone help me shed some light on this and tell me why this is happening?

Comment: can we see any live demo or something?

Comment: No demo needed, the answer I believe is quite clear.

Comment: @ApulGupta unfortunately not, the live code is not public, and in jsfiddle I can't make a call to an external php file.

Comment: @Daedalus please feel free to add your answer if you have an idea on how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are starting your ajax call, but you aren't using the response of your call. The `response` parameter in the `source` function is a callback, which you can trigger after the ajax call is successful.

```
$('#q').autocomplete({
    //source:'getklanten.php'
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "getklanten.php",
            data: {
                term : request.term,
                supplier : $('#zxc').is(':checked')
            },
            success: function(data){
                response(data);
            },
            error: function(){
                response();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

You must always call the `response` callback even if you encounter an error.

See http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source for more Information.

Answer (score 1):

Now, this answer is not tested, but here it is none-the-less.

I believe the problem with your code is based on the fact that you do not call the callback given in the anon function supplied to the source property.

[As is stated in the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source), the response callback must be called, whether the ajax errors out or no, so the widget always has the correct state.

I'm going copy your above code, and add in comments where applicable; but to start off..  Ajax methods don't return anything, unless two options are set, and even then, that's not exactly desired behavior since it slows everything to a stop(synchronous behavior versus async), and waits for the function to complete.

That said, you should simply need to provide the response callback as defined in the documentation:

```
$('#q').autocomplete({
    //source:'getklanten.php'
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "getklanten.php",
          data: {
            term : request.term,
            supplier : $('#zxc').is(':checked')
          },
          success: function(data) {
            response(data); // call the callback
          }
        });
    }
});
```

Of course, you should always handle your errors; the above is just an example, but ideally, you would add the `response()` call to the 'complete' property in the ajax options object, and only fill the data if its applicable, otherwise returning an empty object.

Answer (score -1):

You need to modify your PHP code so that it returns:

```
[{"name":"Company name","id":12345}] // <- note "name" in place of "naam"
```

Comment: This isn't the problem.

Comment: My php checks for the value naam, not name. It's Dutch so as @Daedalus mentions, this is indeed not the problem.